# How do I map a URL to a uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com website

Tags: azure

I have a website running on Azure: -

e.g. mysite.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com

I have purchased a domain e.g. [www.mysite.co.uk](http://www.mysite.co.uk)

When I go to https://www.mysite.co.uk I want to display the website mysite.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com.

I've tried adding an app service in azure, but it gives me the URL https://mysite.azurewebsites.net.

So https://www.mysite.co.uk now brings up a Azure welcome screen asking me to deploy my code.

How do I get https://mysite.co.uk to display https://mysite.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com?

Thanks.
Ian.

Answer (score 1):

I found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-custom-domain-name-portal#add-a-cname-record-for-your-custom-domain

So I deleted my App Service in Azure, as that's not what I needed and followed the above instructions to configure the DNS for cloudapp.

Answer (score 0):

You have to map your custom domain name to the web app. Below is the Microsoft doc with the steps.

[Custom Domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain)

Comment: Thanks, but this tells me how to map www.mysite.co.uk to my app service https://mysite.azurewebsites.net, which I have already done.

But what I need to do is map www.mysite.co.uk to a URL that is on a VM, e.g. https://mysite.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com:44300.